# Turn list of strings into list of dictionaries python

Tags: python, string, dictionary

**Goal**: Turn list of strings into list of dictionaries

I have the following list of strings

```
 info = ['{"contributors": null, "truncated": true,  "text": "hey there"}', 
         '{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "how are you"}',
         '{"contributors": 10, "truncated": false, "text": "howdy"}']
```

**Desired output:**

```
 desired_info = [{"contributors": null, "truncated": true,  "text": "hey there"}, 
 {"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "how are you"},
 {"contributors": 10, "truncated": false, "text": "howdy"}]
```

**Question**: How do I turn list of strings into list of dictionaries?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `json.loads`:

```
import json

info = ['{"contributors": null, "truncated": true,  "text": "hey there"}',
         '{"contributors": null, "truncated": false, "text": "how are you"}',
         '{"contributors": 10, "truncated": false, "text": "howdy"}']

info = [json.loads(x) for x in info]
print(info)
```

Output:

```
[{'contributors': None, 'truncated': True, 'text': 'hey there'}, {'contributors': None, 'truncated': False, 'text': 'how are you'}, {'contributors': 10, 'truncated': False, 'text': 'howdy'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

so if you do:

```
>>> x = ['{"hi": True}']
>>> y = eval(x[0])
>>> y.get("hi")
True
```

so theoretically

```
desired_info = []
for x in info:
    desired_info.append(eval(x))
```

should do the trick.

I'm not sure how proper it is to use eval, but I'm sure someone will fill me in if it isn't.

Comment: An approach like this would work if all of his values were valid Python.  Unfortunately, he is not using python booleans in his input.

Comment: It's better to use `ast.literal_eval` if the syntactically-valid Python code is an object literal. There's no need to allow arbitrary code execution for that.